# I've been granted a Japanese visa with a validity of 15 days. How do I calculate the day on which I'll have to leave the country?

Tags: japan, visa-free-entry, visa-expiration

If I have a visa waiver that grants me a maximum of 15 days per stay, and I arrive in Japan on the 1st of March at 8 p.m., what is my last date of departure?

Is it the 15th of March (because the arrival date is counted as day 1 regardless of arrival time)?

Alternatively, is it the 16th of March (calculated by adding 15 x 24 hours to the arrival date and time)?

I emailed my enquiry to Japan's immigration last week. I haven't received a reply yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Normally it is the 16th of March, but the hours are not taken into account. The arrival day is Day 0, so to speak. The date will be reflected on your landing permission stamp, e.g. [image: Japanese landing permission stamps, one of which shows 4.JUL.2012 as the date of the permit and 19.JUL.2012 as the date until which the permission is valid.]

The immigration inspector reserves the right to give landing permission shorter than the maximum and you should note that unforeseen circumstances (e.g. weather, train/taxi breakdowns) may cause you to miss your departure time if you plan your stay too "tightly" with the rules.

Comment: @jcaron I couldn't find a textual source, but that is how it is computed on the landing stamps, e.g. https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Japan_entry_and_exit_stamps.jpg.

Comment: Thank you. I've finally received a reply from the immigration, and it is consistent with your reply. I quote, "it is counted from the next day of the arrival in Japan."